# How to end a CallKit call from custom UI without having caller UUID?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I working on a video call application in iOS Swift 5, where call can only initiate from the backend web app and the mobile app can only answer to those calls,. Means there is no mobile-mobile communication, communication between web app and mobile app. In my application I'm using PushKit with CallKit for notifying the incoming call in the background or killed state. So in the background or killed state, if I get an incoming call, it will show the calling screen using CallKit and if I pressed Answer button, it will navigate to my own custom video call screen where I have end button for dismissing the call. But when I press the end button, the VoIP call get disconnected. But the CallKit call is not dismissing(Still show the green bar on the top of Homescreen). And I checked for how ending the CallKit call via code, but in most of the solution the CallKit is dismissing with the use of callUUID. But I don't know from where I will get that UUID. In some code I saw the UUID is received from the push payload, but in my case the call is initiated from the web app, so I'm not receiving the caller UUID. Please help me.
This is my code,

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
     print(payload.dictionaryPayload)
     let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
     if state == .background || state == .inactive {
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: callerName)
        update.hasVideo = true
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(), update: update, completion: { error in      })
     } else if state == .active {
        // no need for calling screen
     }
  }
```

And I tired the following code to end the call, but not working.

```
func endCall(call: UUID) {
    let callController = CXCallController()
    let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: call)
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endCallAction)
    callController.request(transaction) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("EndCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription).")
            self.provider.reportCall(with: call, endedAt: Date(), reason: .remoteEnded)
            return
        }

        print("EndCallAction transaction request successful")

 }
```

Here I'm passing call as current UUID, then I'm getting error response as

> EndCallAction transaction request failed: The operation couldn’t be
> completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uuid value is one that you provide.

You are providing it here:

```
provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(),...
```

Because you are simply allocating a new UUID and passing it directly in `reportNewIncomingCall` you don't know the uuid when you need it later.

You need to store this uuid in a property so that you can provide it to your `endCall` function.

Comment: So you mean when I report a new incoming call with UUID, I need to store same UUID in preference and can use the same when endCall right?

Comment: That's right. The uuid is something you provide to callkit so that you can identify the call later